Macbook Pro 2011 slow
I have a strange issue with my Macbook.

Macbook Pro (13" late 2011)
Memory 4GB
Processor Intel 2.4GHZ
Graphics Intel HD
Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6
Two original Power Adapters 60W

A week ago my battery failed and the Macbook became very slow all the time under any condition. This makes all sense to me. After replacing the battery the condition changed (improved a lot). Anyhow, I decided also to do a clean reinstall of Sierra after so many years, which went without any problems. The following problem description is the same for the time before and after the re-install of Sierra.
Here is what happens:

When charged a 100% while using the power adapter the mac gets very, very slow. The activity monitor is showing kernel CPU usage of up to 500%, the system is running at ~93%, user load is normal with ~8%. The activity monitor is not showing any processes with excessive energy consumption. Memory consumption is normal too. The Mac works well until the battery is fully charged.
As soon as I disconnect the power adapter and the Mac is only running on battery the kernel goes down, system and user CPU load is running below 10% and all is back to normal. As soon as the battery charge goes down to ~95% or less, all is good again also with the re-connected power adapter.
The problem repeats itself any time when the battery gets fully charged.
No difference with different power adapters.
The charging process and time seems to be absolutely normal.
No difference with or without third party hardware connected.
SMC / PRAM reset does not make a difference.
Virus and malware check negative.
Mac HD drive checks all good, no problems, no repair was required.
Only when running in Safe mode, the Mac works well under any power supply and charge condition.
Temperatures for battery, CPU and GPU as well as related fan speeds are all normal under any condition, also when the problem occurs.
Over night I am leaving the Mac in sleep. It seems that the Mac shuts down at times automatically, but than also reboots on its own since there is a message in the morning that the external drive was not ejected correctly.

My best guess is an internal energy supply issue, but I have no idea how to continue from here. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone in advance.
UPDATE

Ran the Battery completely empty.
Recharged after that fully.
Performed SMS / PRAM reset before restart.
Strangely the battery Health (coconut) went from 100% to 101,2%
The maximum capacity went from 5900mAh (which is also the design capacity) to 5971mAh.
Problem remains the same and occurs only with full battery and charger attached.

UPDATE
Here are the launchdaemons: ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons; kmutil showloaded | grep -v com.apple
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  647 Dec 27 22:20 com.crystalidea.macsfancontrol.smcwrite.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  886 May  1  2022 com.displaylink.displaylinkmanager.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 joerg  wheel  568 Mar 10  2011 com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  829 Dec 28 11:25 com.wdc.WDPrivilegedHelper.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  833 Dec 27 18:38 jp.co.canon.MasterInstaller.plist
-bash: kmutil: command not found
Update
New Terminal results:
ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons; kextstat -l | grep -v com.apple
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  647 Dec 27 22:20 com.crystalidea.macsfancontrol.smcwrite.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  886 May  1  2022 com.displaylink.displaylinkmanager.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 joerg  wheel  568 Mar 10  2011 com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  829 Dec 28 11:25 com.wdc.WDPrivilegedHelper.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel  833 Dec 27 18:38 jp.co.canon.MasterInstaller.plist
15    0 0xffffff7f80c5b000 0x10000    0x10000    com.displaylink.driver.DisplayLinkDriver (4.3 (206)) 21BA08D2-055E-380E-B526-1798079CF68D <14 12 5 4 3>

Since the problem is not reproducible in safe mode, it's caused by software. You might as well start by removing all "antivirus" software, since it's worse than useless and may well be at fault. It has to be removed according to the developer's instructions, not by just dragging something to the Trash, and merely disabling it by clicking a button is not enough.

Who did the battery replacement, and where did the replacement come from?

It sounds like some oddity of the Power Management Unit, which are prone to error and failure with time. Ultimately, this is a 14-year-old Mac.

The problem also occurs without "antivirus" software. The battery was replaced by a certified Mac store, the manufacturer of the battery is "Simplo".

Please add the output (if any) of the following shell command to your question. Kindly post the text in a code block, not a screenshot. ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons; kmutil showloaded | grep -v com.apple

Here are the LaunchDaemons:

The second part of that command was wrong for your OS version. Please add this output: kextstat -l | grep -v com.apple Meanwhile, I suggest you remove the fan-control software, DisplayLink, and the Western Digital vendor software according to the instructions of the respective developers.

@ Linc, thank you, will do, here is the updated Terminal information. Strange only, this setup is running on my Mac well since ~ 4 years. Thank you again for your help.

There's nothing new in that additional information. You have the third-party system modifications that I mentioned in my last comment. The only way to rule them out as culprits is to remove them and test. If they haven't been updated in years, they're almost certainly out of date. If you can still reproduce the problem without any of that software on board, we'll have to think about something else.

Linc, Fan Control and WD is completely removed including a manual library clean up. I left Displaylink which is maybe not the best solution, but I need the convenience of using two monitors. I am not aware about any other cost efficient options to do that. However, the machine is running fine the whole day since 12 hours. Thank you especially and anybody else for their assistance. A happy new year to everyone. Thanks again

Glad to hear it. Make sure DisplayLink is updated to the latest version compatible with your OS.

I can confirm that DisplayLink is updated to latest compatible version with Sierra 10.12.6. Thank you again

According to the OP, his problem was caused by either or both of two third-party system modifications (which may have been outdated): "Macs Fan Control" and "WD Drive Utilities." Apparently at least one of these didn't interact well with the replacement battery.
